# AWS Glue Crawler registers JSON array keys as struct

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, web-crawler, classification, aws-glue

I have configured a crawler in AWS Glue to create a table from nested JSON log files. But the JSON files contain an array key (UUID) that is registered as part of the structure. Do anyone know if it is possible to skip the array keys (UUID) in the table structure?

Because if we have already created a table by crawler, the update crawler get a "Internal exception error" message.

**JSON structure**

```
{  
"reference": "f41a6c6a",
"items": {
    "21567d9a89af": {          
    "id": "21567d9a89af",
    "name": "PRODUCTNAME"
  }
}
```

**Catalog Structure**

```
reference
items
- 21567d9a89af
- - id
- - name
```

**Desired outcome**

```
reference
items
- id
- name
```